# Graphics Panel Resizing

Tags: java

This is the updates code changing to JPanel. It is showing the display but I cant seem to move the turtle even through making a class and trying to move it from commands.

What else I need to do to display it in the center?

Also, will it be easy to add all of the code I did from the last version

Thanks

```
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JFrame
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
```

{

```
        });
  }

  private static void createAndShowGUI() {
      System.out.println("Created GUI on EDT? "+          
      f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); 
      f.add(new GraphicsPanel());
      f.pack();
      f.setVisible(true);
image.getHeight());
}

public void setballColour(Color col)
{
    Graphics g = ballDisplay.getGraphics();
    g.setColor(col);
    g.fillRect(0, 0, ballDisplay.getWidth(),  ballDisplay.getHeight()); }

    @Override
     public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);
            g.drawImage(ballDisplay, xPos-Object_X_SIZE/2, yPos-Object_Y_SIZE/2, null);                 

    // render the image on the panel.
    g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);
    g.drawImage(ballDisplay, xPos-Object_X_SIZE/2, yPos-Object_Y_SIZE/2, null); }

/**
 * Constructor.
 */
public PanelMy() {

    setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black));}

     public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(800,400);
     }
     {


    //main drawing area
    image = new Scanner(800, 400, Scanner.TYPE_INT_RGB);
```

Comment: Do you want to fix the jtextfield size with the mainframe?

Comment: @IsuruDilshan Yes :) when I type in the box it takes up the mainframe so I cannot see what the turtle is doing.

Comment: So know you "un-accept" all the answer after all the help you have been given. I guess you really don't want any help in the future.

Answer (score 2):

> I want to be able to resize the JTextField

```
private JTextField console = new JTextField(15);
```

The above will cause the text field to size itself to hold 15 letters (not pixels) the size of a "W" for the given font.

> For example they can type in "forward", "turnleft", "turnright", etc.

Since the largest word is only 9 characters you should use:

```
private JTextField console = new JTextField(9);
```

as the maximum.

You may fine 7 or 8 is even better.

Edit:

Well you have some problems with the structure of your code:

```
console.setForeground(Color.red);
console.setBounds(80,20,250,50);
add(console);
```

The above code is where you set the size/location of the console. So basically you are ignoring the "preferred size" of the text field and just using a random size like (250, 50).

Also, the text field only appear by chance at that location because of the design problems in your code.

```
@Override
public void paint(Graphics g) 
{

    // render the image on the panel.
    g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);
    g.drawImage(turtleDisplay, xPos-TURTLE_X_SIZE/2, yPos-TURTLE_Y_SIZE/2, null);
}
```

You should NOT be overriding the paint() method of a JFrame. A JFrame is just a container and should not contain any application logic. By doing so you are losing default functionality of the frame such as double buffering and painting child components.

Custom painting is done by overriding the `paintComponent(...)` method of a JPanel. The first statement should then be `super.paintComponent(..)` to make sure default painting functionality is used. Then you add the panel to the frame.

Then you can add your text field to this panel and it will display properly.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) for more information

Comment: Hi camickr, thanks for replying :) I ended up wording the question wrong as I meant to say I wanted to change the size of the console as it is too big when I type in as it covers the turtles movement (if that makes sense). Sorry for the inconvenience

Comment: Hey, I have just edited the code above to the JPanel version. It's going great so far but just my turtle is stuck in the top left. I have updated the code to show you what I mean :)

Comment: @ben, look you have already "accepted" an answer (even though it wasn't very helpful). In any case you don't go around changing the entire question. You have a new problem so you ask a new question. And I'm still not going to help because you still have posted way too much code. You were asked to implement "one function at a time".  So first you just get the motion going forward. Once that works you try changing direction. So get reid of all the unnecessary code. We don't have time to look at it!!!

Comment: `but just my turtle is stuck in the top left.`  and why do you expect it to move? You haven't added the text field and you haven't added an ActionListener so the user has no way to move the turtle. I am tired of repeating my suggestions 2 or 3 times. The only hint I will give you is that if you want the panel to repaint itself you need to invoke repaint() on the panel when you change a property of the panel, like the turtles location.

Comment: sorry, I have been using a framework from someone who has already made the turlte movements etc. I have only added the JPanel to it and made the application . They have done the commands and TurtleDisplay

Comment: I wont waste your time anymore

Comment: `I have been using a framework from someone who has already made the turlte movements etc` - so that doesn't prevent you from keeping that code separate and then only add back in one method at a time, once you figure out basic movement of the turtle. Again. small steps. It is easier to look at 20 line of code than hundreds of lines of code to see what is happening. You can then add debug statements to the code to follow the flow order.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code. Use layouts. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html

```
//JTextField font colour//
console.setForeground(Color.red);
console.setBounds(80, 20, 250, 50);

javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
layout.setHorizontalGroup(
    layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
    .addComponent(console)
);
layout.setVerticalGroup(
    layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
    .addComponent(console)
);

add(console);
setSize(200, 100);
setVisible(true);
```

Sorry, I just forget to read your full comment. The following code will fix the size of jtextfiled

```
//JTextField font colour//
        console.setForeground(Color.red);
        console.setBounds(80, 20, 250, 50);

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addComponent(console, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 77, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(0, 323, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addComponent(console, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(0, 280, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        add(console);
        setSize(200, 100);
```

Comment: Thanks for your help I really appreciate it!

Comment: @Ben, have you tried resizing your frame? I'll bet the JTextField disappears.

Comment: @camickr when I run and resize it does disappear yes.. I am having a lot of problems with it at the moment and feel like giving up

Comment: @Ben, well, I explained your problems and you aren't willing to take the time to listen to my suggestions and read the tutorial. And as I commented in your other question the secret is to learn to walk before you run. Why would you ever write all the code for menus before you can even display an image on a panel. Write small blocks of code and test it before writing the code for the entire project.