# Graphics JPanel Sizing

Tags: java, oop, jpanel, turtle-graphics

I have made a turtle graphics panel which allows a turtle move from user inputs such as `forward <distance>`, `turnright`, `turnleft`, etc. However, I don't know how to move the turtle as it is stuck at the top left of the screen. Does anyone know what I am doing wrong with the code and could adjust it for me? I want it to be directly in the center with the pen down

Here is a picture of the application so far [Turtle Graphics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xKC4j.png)

**First class**

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JMenu;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

/**
 * Represents the graphics display panel within the turtle program. This panel contains an image which is updated to reflect user commands.
 * 
 * 
 * 
 */
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class GraphicsPanel extends JPanel 
{

    private JTextField console = new JTextField(15);


       public static void main(String[] args) {


           SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

       public void run() {

                 createAndShowGUI(); 
                }
            });
      }

       JMenuBar myMenuBar;
       JMenu file;
       JMenu help;
       JMenuItem load;
       JMenuItem save;



      private static void createAndShowGUI() {
          System.out.println("Created GUI on EDT? "+
          SwingUtilities.isEventDispatchThread());
          JFrame f = new JFrame("Turtle Graphics");
          f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); 
          f.add(new GraphicsPanel());
          f.pack();
          f.setVisible(true);
      } 


    /**
     * The default BG colour of the image.
     */
    private final static Color BACKGROUND_COL = Color.DARK_GRAY;
    private final static int TURTLE_X_SIZE = 8, TURTLE_Y_SIZE = 8;

    /**
     * The underlying image used for drawing. This is required so any previous drawing activity is persistent on the panel.
     */
    private BufferedImage image, turtleDisplay;

    //djm added
    private Color PenColour = Color.RED;
    private boolean penDown = false;
    private int xPos=0, yPos=0;
    private int direction = 180; //robot pointing down the screen;
    private JMenuItem newfile;
    private JMenuItem exit;
    private JMenuItem about;

        /**
     * Draw a line on the image using the given colour.
     * 
     * @param color
     * @param x1
     * @param y1
     * @param x2
     * @param y2
     */
    public void drawLine(Color color, int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2) 
    {

        Graphics g = image.getGraphics();
        g.setColor(color);
        g.drawLine(x1, y1, x2, y2);
    }

    //djm added commands
    public void penDown()
    {
        penDown = true;
    }

    public void penUp()
    {
        penDown = false;
    }

    public void turnRight()
    {
        direction +=90;
        if (direction >= 360)
            direction = 0;
    }

    public void turnLeft()
    {
        direction -=90;
        if (direction < 0)
            direction = 270;
    }

    public void forward(int distance)
    {
        //Graphics g = image.getGraphics();
        int x=xPos,y=yPos;
        //stored xPos and yPos are current location
        if (direction == 0) //robot facing up the screen, so forward subtracts y
        {
            y = yPos-distance;
        }
        else if (direction == 90) //robot facing right so forward add x
        {
            x = xPos + distance;
        }
        else if (direction == 180) //robot facing down the screen, so forwards adds to y
        {
            y = yPos + distance;
        }
        else if (direction == 270) //robot facing left, so forwards subtracts from x
        {
            x = xPos - distance;
        }
        else 
        {
            System.out.println("strange, shouldn't get here");
        }
        if (penDown)
        {
            //x=400; y=400;
            drawLine(PenColour, xPos, yPos, x, y);
            //g.drawLine(xPos,yPos,x,y);
        }
        //now robot has moved to the new position
        xPos = x;
        yPos = y;
    }

    /**
     * Clears the image contents.
     */
    public void clear() 
    {

        Graphics g = image.getGraphics();
        g.setColor(BACKGROUND_COL);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, image.getWidth(),  image.getHeight());
    }

    public void setTurtleColour(Color col)
    {
        Graphics g = turtleDisplay.getGraphics();
        g.setColor(col);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, turtleDisplay.getWidth(),  turtleDisplay.getHeight()); }

    public void green()
    {
        setTurtleColour(Color.GREEN);
        Graphics g = image.getGraphics();
        g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        PenColour = Color.GREEN;

    }

    public void black()
    {
        setTurtleColour(Color.BLACK);
        Graphics g = image.getGraphics();
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        PenColour = Color.BLACK;

    }


        @Override
         public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
                super.paintComponent(g);
                g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);
                g.drawImage(turtleDisplay, xPos-TURTLE_X_SIZE/2, yPos-TURTLE_Y_SIZE/2, null);

 repaint();



        // render the image on the panel.
        g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);
        g.drawImage(turtleDisplay, xPos-TURTLE_X_SIZE/2, yPos-TURTLE_Y_SIZE/2, null); }




    /**
     * Constructor.
     */
    public GraphicsPanel() {
        add(console);

        console.addActionListener(new ActionListener()

                //Command List//

                {
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) 
                    {
                        if (console.getText().contains("penup"))
                        {
                            penUp();
                        }
                        else if (console.getText().contains("pendown"))
                        {
                            penDown();
                        }
                        else if (console.getText().contains("turnleft"))
                        {
                            turnLeft();
                        }
                        else if (console.getText().contains("turnright"))
                        {
                            turnRight();
                        }
                        else if (console.getText().contains("forward"))
                        {
                            forward(direction);
                        }


                        else if (console.getText().contains("reset"))
                        {
                            clear();
                        }

                        else if (console.getText().contains("red"))
                        {
                            setTurtleColour(PenColour);
                        }

                        else if (console.getText().contains("green"))
                        {
                            green();
                        }

                        else if (console.getText().contains("black"))
                        {
                            black();
                        }

                        else
                        {
                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(console, "Invalid command, try again");
                        }

                        console.setText("");
                    }

                });

        myMenuBar = new JMenuBar ();
        file = new JMenu ("File");
        help = new JMenu("Help");
        load = new JMenuItem("Load");
        save = new JMenuItem("Save");
        newfile = new JMenuItem("New");
        exit = new JMenuItem("Exit");
        about = new JMenuItem("About");


        file.add(load);
        file.add(save);
        file.add(newfile);
        file.add(exit);
        help.add(about);

        myMenuBar.add(file);
        myMenuBar.add(help);

        add(myMenuBar);




        setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black));}


         public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
                return new Dimension(800,400);
         }
         {


        //main drawing area
        image = new BufferedImage(800, 400, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);

        //small image to display on top of drawing area to represent the turtle
        turtleDisplay =  new BufferedImage(TURTLE_X_SIZE, TURTLE_Y_SIZE, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);

        //set up turtle
        setTurtleColour(PenColour);

        // Set max size of the panel, so that is matches the max size of the image.
        setMaximumSize(new Dimension(image.getWidth(), image.getHeight()));
        setSize(800,400);
        setVisible(true);

        clear();
    }
}
```

**Second Class**

```
public class turtleClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {

        turtleClass m = new turtleClass();
        m.go();

    }

    public void go ()
    {
        GraphicsPanel p = new GraphicsPanel ();
        p.turnLeft();
        p.forward(100);
        p.turnRight();
        p.penDown();
        p.forward(400);
    }



}
```

Comment: Please don't deface your question. Once you ask a question on this site, your question and its code becomes property of the site as per the terms of service that  you agreed to on joining the site.

Answer (score 1):

I would comment this, but I don't have enough rep points.

I don't see you calling repaint() after any of your methods, so this could be the problem.

~~EDIT~~
I was able to fix your code on my machine but I had to change the entire structure, the repaint() method is the problem, but you have quite a few structural problems as well.

heres an example of how you should structure it, I created 1 extra file that extends JFrame and added your JPanel to it I also deleted your main method in the JPanel class:

this is a rough draw up but I'll let you handle the rest.

```
public class myFrame extends JFrame{

    public GraphicsPanel panel;

    public myFrame() {
         panel = new GraphicsPanel();
        add(panel);

    }

       public void go ()
        {
            panel.turnLeft();
            panel.forward(100);
            panel.turnRight();
            panel.penDown();
            panel.forward(400);
            repaint();
        }
}
```

*Original class without main and a few other modifications*

```
    /**
 * Represents the graphics display panel within the turtle program. This panel contains an image which is updated to reflect user commands.
 * 
 * 
 * 
 */
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class GraphicsPanel extends JPanel 
{

private JTextField console = new JTextField(15);

   JMenuBar myMenuBar;
   JMenu file;
   JMenu help;
   JMenuItem load;
   JMenuItem save;



/**
 * The default BG colour of the image.
 */
private final static Color BACKGROUND_COL = Color.DARK_GRAY;
private final static int TURTLE_X_SIZE = 8, TURTLE_Y_SIZE = 8;

/**
 * The underlying image used for drawing. This is required so any previous drawing activity is persistent on the panel.
 */
private BufferedImage image, turtleDisplay;

//djm added
private Color PenColour = Color.RED;
private boolean penDown = false;
private int xPos=0, yPos=0;
private int direction = 180; //robot pointing down the screen;
private JMenuItem newfile;
private JMenuItem exit;
private JMenuItem about;

    /**
 * Draw a line on the image using the given colour.
 * 
 * @param color
 * @param x1
 * @param y1
 * @param x2
 * @param y2
 */
public void drawLine(Color color, int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2) 
{

    Graphics g = image.getGraphics();
    g.setColor(color);
    g.drawLine(x1, y1, x2, y2);
}

//djm added commands
public void penDown()
{
    penDown = true;
}

public void penUp()
{
    penDown = false;
}

public void turnRight()
{
    direction +=90;
    if (direction >= 360)
        direction = 0;
}

public void turnLeft()
{
    direction -=90;
    if (direction < 0)
        direction = 270;
}

public void forward(int distance)
{
    //Graphics g = image.getGraphics();
    int x=xPos,y=yPos;
    //stored xPos and yPos are current location
    if (direction == 0) //robot facing up the screen, so forward subtracts y
    {
        y = yPos-distance;
    }
    else if (direction == 90) //robot facing right so forward add x
    {
        x = xPos + distance;
    }
    else if (direction == 180) //robot facing down the screen, so forwards adds to y
    {
        y = yPos + distance;
    }
    else if (direction == 270) //robot facing left, so forwards subtracts from x
    {
        x = xPos - distance;
    }
    else 
    {
        System.out.println("strange, shouldn't get here");
    }
    if (penDown)
    {
        //x=400; y=400;
        drawLine(PenColour, xPos, yPos, x, y);
        //g.drawLine(xPos,yPos,x,y);
    }
    //now robot has moved to the new position
    xPos = x;
    yPos = y;

}

/**
 * Clears the image contents.
 */
public void clear() 
{

    Graphics g = image.getGraphics();
    g.setColor(BACKGROUND_COL);
    g.fillRect(0, 0, image.getWidth(),  image.getHeight());
}

public void setTurtleColour(Color col)
{
    Graphics g = turtleDisplay.getGraphics();
    g.setColor(col);
    g.fillRect(0, 0, turtleDisplay.getWidth(),  turtleDisplay.getHeight()); }

public void green()
{
    setTurtleColour(Color.GREEN);
    Graphics g = image.getGraphics();
    g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
    PenColour = Color.GREEN;

}

public void black()
{
    setTurtleColour(Color.BLACK);
    Graphics g = image.getGraphics();
    g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    PenColour = Color.BLACK;

}


    @Override
     public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);
            g.drawImage(turtleDisplay, xPos-TURTLE_X_SIZE/2, yPos-TURTLE_Y_SIZE/2, null);



    // render the image on the panel.
    g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);
    g.drawImage(turtleDisplay, xPos-TURTLE_X_SIZE/2, yPos-TURTLE_Y_SIZE/2, null); }




/**
 * Constructor.
 */
public GraphicsPanel() {
    add(console);

    console.addActionListener(new ActionListener()

            //Command List//

            {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) 
                {
                    if (console.getText().contains("penup"))
                    {
                        penUp();
                    }
                    else if (console.getText().contains("pendown"))
                    {
                        penDown();
                    }
                    else if (console.getText().contains("turnleft"))
                    {
                        turnLeft();
                    }
                    else if (console.getText().contains("turnright"))
                    {
                        turnRight();
                    }
                    else if (console.getText().contains("forward"))
                    {
                        forward(direction);
                    }


                    else if (console.getText().contains("reset"))
                    {
                        clear();
                    }

                    else if (console.getText().contains("red"))
                    {
                        setTurtleColour(PenColour);
                    }

                    else if (console.getText().contains("green"))
                    {
                        green();
                    }

                    else if (console.getText().contains("black"))
                    {
                        black();
                    }

                    else
                    {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(console, "Invalid command, try again");
                    }

                    console.setText("");
                }

            });

    myMenuBar = new JMenuBar ();
    file = new JMenu ("File");
    help = new JMenu("Help");
    load = new JMenuItem("Load");
    save = new JMenuItem("Save");
    newfile = new JMenuItem("New");
    exit = new JMenuItem("Exit");
    about = new JMenuItem("About");


    file.add(load);
    file.add(save);
    file.add(newfile);
    file.add(exit);
    help.add(about);

    myMenuBar.add(file);
    myMenuBar.add(help);

    add(myMenuBar);




    setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black));}


     public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(800,400);
     }
     {


    //main drawing area
    image = new BufferedImage(800, 400, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);

    //small image to display on top of drawing area to represent the turtle
    turtleDisplay =  new BufferedImage(TURTLE_X_SIZE, TURTLE_Y_SIZE, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);

    //set up turtle
    setTurtleColour(PenColour);

    // Set max size of the panel, so that is matches the max size of the image.
    setMaximumSize(new Dimension(image.getWidth(), image.getHeight()));
    setSize(800,400);
    setVisible(true);

    clear();
}
```

}

*Your turtle class*

```
public class turtleClass {

public static void main(String[] args) 
{

    myFrame m = new myFrame();
    System.out.println("Created GUI on EDT? "+
            SwingUtilities.isEventDispatchThread());
            m.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); 
            m.pack();
                m.setVisible(true);
                m.go();

    }
}
```

Comment: @Ben take a look at my edit, see if you can fix it with the changes I made, maybe you can add a constructor to your graphics panel and set the initial values through that.

Comment: Hey, no problem. I am not entirely sure what you mean by putting the main method back in the code. You have two values in your code: private boolean penDown = false;
private int xPos=0, yPos=0; try changing these to true, and setting the screen width/2 and height/2  to xPos and yPos.

Comment: @Ben is this the code in your question giving this error? And are your running this through terminal or an IDE? Make sure your running the class with the main method in it, i.e If its the code I posted make sure turtle class is the class you launch from.

Comment: `but I had to change the entire structure, the repaint() method is the problem, but you have quite a few structural problems as well.` yes and the OP has been told this numerous times in his other postings: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50308119/java-turtle-graphics-panel-resizing-jtextfield

Comment: @Ben glad I could help :)

Comment: `Original class without main and a few other modifications` what is the point of that. Nobody knows what has been changed unless you do a line by line comparison. The point of answering a question is to explain the problem and point the OP to the part of the code that is causing the problem so the OP can fix the problem. `I created 1 extra file that extends JFrame and` - NO you should not be extending JFrame. The OP has been told this 4 questions ago. Please read the Swing tutorials on "Custom Painting" for a better way to structure the code. Don't encourage the poor program design.

Comment: @camickr I meant to say nothing significant worth noting. Meaning just repositioning somethings the way I would do it, but over all everything he added is still there just deleted the main method, however I do see where it is unclear. As for extending JFrame it is what my graphics professor has taught me, so I'll read the documentation you pointed out, but I had no intention of encouraging "poor program design"

Comment: @camickr could you please link me to the specific page in the documentation you are referring to, I would like to read it so I can get a better understanding myself. Thank you.

Comment: Take a look at the [Swing tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/TOC.html). There is no specific page that says 'don't do this". But the examples are designed to show a reasonable way to create a frame with Swing components. Some of the examples are old, but most have been updated to show the better way. The general design rule for Java classes is to extend a class only when you add new functionality to the class. Adding components to a frame is not new functionality so there is no reason to extend it.

Comment: You can do a search on the web using "composition vs inheritance" and you will find articles talking about this general design concept. Read a few articles to better understand the concept.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you're finished making changes to your graphics buffer, you need to call `repaint()` to make those changes visible to the user.  Even when changing pen color, even though the color won't apply until the next thing we draw, we call `repaint()` so that the turtle cursor itself displays in the new color.  Ditto for `clear()`, `forward()` (pen up or down), etc.  If your turtle cursor had a non-symmetrical shape (eg. arrow or actual turtle) then even `turnLeft()` and `turnRight()` would need to trigger a `repaint()` to display the new turtle heading.

Along with adding missing calls to `repaint()`, here's my rework of your code that makes the commands you have operate correctly:

**GraphicsPanel.java**

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JMenu;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

/*
 * Represents the graphics display panel within the turtle program. This panel contains an image
 * which is updated to reflect user commands.
 */

public class GraphicsPanel extends JPanel 
{
    private JTextField console = new JTextField(15);

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGUI(); 
            }
        });
    }

    JMenuBar menuBar;
    JMenu file;
    JMenu help;
    JMenuItem load;
    JMenuItem save;

    private static void createAndShowGUI() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Turtle Graphics");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); 
        frame.add(new GraphicsPanel());
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    } 

    /*
     * The default BG colour of the image.
     */

    private final static Color BACKGROUND_COL = Color.DARK_GRAY;
    private final static int TURTLE_X_SIZE = 8, TURTLE_Y_SIZE = 8;

    /*
     * The underlying image used for drawing. This is required so 
     * any previous drawing activity is persistent on the panel.
     */

    private BufferedImage image, turtleDisplay;

    // djm added
    private Color PenColour = Color.RED;
    private boolean penDown = true;
    private int xPos = 400 - TURTLE_X_SIZE/2, yPos = 200 - TURTLE_Y_SIZE/2;
    private int direction = 180; // robot pointing down the screen
    private JMenuItem newfile;
    private JMenuItem exit;
    private JMenuItem about;
    private int distance = 100;

    /*
     * Draw a line on the image using the given colour.
     */

    public void drawLine(Color color, int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2) 
    {

        Graphics graphics = image.getGraphics();

        graphics.setColor(color);
        graphics.drawLine(x1, y1, x2, y2);
    }

    // djm added commands
    public void penDown()
    {
        penDown = true;
    }

    public void penUp()
    {
        penDown = false;
    }

    public void turnRight()
    {
        direction += 90;

        if (direction >= 360)
        {
            direction -= 360;
        }
    }

    public void turnLeft()
    {
        direction -= 90;

        if (direction < 0)
        {
            direction += 360;
        }
    }

    public void forward(int distance)
    {
        int x = xPos, y = yPos;

        // stored xPos and yPos are current location
        if (direction == 0) // robot facing up the screen, so forward subtracts y
        {
            y = yPos - distance;
        }
        else if (direction == 90) // robot facing right so forward add x
        {
            x = xPos + distance;
        }
        else if (direction == 180) // robot facing down the screen, so forwards adds to y
        {
            y = yPos + distance;
        }
        else if (direction == 270) // robot facing left, so forwards subtracts from x
        {
            x = xPos - distance;
        }
        else 
        {
            System.out.println("strange, shouldn't get here");
        }

        if (penDown)
        {
            drawLine(PenColour, xPos, yPos, x, y);
        }

        // now robot has moved to the new position
        xPos = x;
        yPos = y;

        repaint();
    }

    /*
     * Clear the image contents.
     */

    public void clear() 
    {
        Graphics graphics = image.getGraphics();

        graphics.setColor(BACKGROUND_COL);
        graphics.fillRect(0, 0, image.getWidth(), image.getHeight());

        repaint();
    }

    public void setColour(Color color)
    {
        Graphics graphics = turtleDisplay.getGraphics();
        graphics.setColor(color);
        graphics.fillRect(0, 0, turtleDisplay.getWidth(), turtleDisplay.getHeight());

        graphics = image.getGraphics();
        graphics.setColor(color);

        PenColour = color;

        repaint();
    }

    public void green()
    {
        setColour(Color.GREEN);
    }

    public void red()
    {
        setColour(Color.RED);
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics graphics) {
        super.paintComponent(graphics);

        graphics.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);
        graphics.drawImage(turtleDisplay, xPos - TURTLE_X_SIZE/2, yPos - TURTLE_Y_SIZE/2, null);
    }

    /*
     * Constructor.
     */

    public GraphicsPanel() {
        add(console);

        console.addActionListener(new ActionListener()

            /* Command List */

            {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) 
                {
                    if (console.getText().contains("penup"))
                    {
                        penUp();
                    }
                    else if (console.getText().contains("pendown"))
                    {
                        penDown();
                    }
                    else if (console.getText().contains("turnleft"))
                    {
                        turnLeft();
                    }
                    else if (console.getText().contains("turnright"))
                    {
                        turnRight();
                    }
                    else if (console.getText().contains("forward"))
                    {
                        forward(distance);
                    }
                    else if (console.getText().contains("reset"))
                    {
                        clear();
                    }
                    else if (console.getText().contains("green"))
                    {
                        green();
                    }
                    else if (console.getText().contains("red"))
                    {
                        red();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(console, "Invalid command, try again");
                    }

                    console.setText("");
                }
            }
        );

        menuBar = new JMenuBar();

        file = new JMenu("File");

        load = new JMenuItem("Load");
        save = new JMenuItem("Save");
        newfile = new JMenuItem("New");
        exit = new JMenuItem("Exit");

        file.add(load);
        file.add(save);
        file.add(newfile);
        file.add(exit);

        menuBar.add(file);

        help = new JMenu("Help");

        about = new JMenuItem("About");

        help.add(about);

        menuBar.add(help);

        add(menuBar);

        setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black));
    }

    public Dimension getPreferredSize()
    {
        return new Dimension(800, 400);
    }

    {
        // main drawing area
        image = new BufferedImage(800, 400, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);

        // small image to display on top of drawing area to represent the turtle
        turtleDisplay = new BufferedImage(TURTLE_X_SIZE, TURTLE_Y_SIZE, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);

        // set up turtle
        setColour(PenColour);

        // Set max size of the panel, so that is matches the max size of the image.
        setMaximumSize(new Dimension(image.getWidth(), image.getHeight()));
        setSize(800, 400);
        setVisible(true);

        clear();
    }
}
```

**TurtleClass.java**

```
import java.awt.Graphics;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class TurtleClass extends JFrame {

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new TurtleClass();
            }
        });
    }

    public TurtleClass()
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Turtle Graphics");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        GraphicsPanel panel = new GraphicsPanel();

        frame.add(panel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);

        panel.turnLeft();
        panel.forward(100);
        panel.turnRight();
        panel.penDown();
        panel.forward(400);
    }
}
```

You can still run this from the TurtleClass or GraphicsPanel as you originally designed:

[image]

I would drop the console when invoked as a *library* like TurtleClass does but keep it when invoked as an *application* as GraphicsPanel does.  It could then be both and output device and an interactive environment depending on need.

Comment: @Ben, done.  However, you ought to understand your code well enough to make such a trivial change yourself.